# Difference in years,months and days between 2 hijri dates

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, time

Please can anyone provide a method to calculate the difference between 2 hijri dates thanks in advance

i tried this code

```
            HijriCalendar hijriCal=new HijriCalendar();
            DateTimeFormatInfo DTFormat = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-sa", false).DateTimeFormat;
            DTFormat.Calendar = new System.Globalization.HijriCalendar();
            DTFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
            string HijriDate = FromDate.Date.ToString("d", DTFormat);
            string[] fromDateParams=HijriDate.Split('/');
            HijriDate = ToDate.Date.ToString("d", DTFormat);
            string[] toDateParams = HijriDate.Split('/');
            DateTime fromDateHijri = new DateTime(hijriCal.GetYear(FromDate), hijriCal.GetMonth(FromDate), int.Parse(fromDateParams[0]), hijriCal);
            DateTime toDateHijri = new DateTime(hijriCal.GetYear(ToDate), hijriCal.GetMonth(ToDate), int.Parse(toDateParams[0]), hijriCal);

            TimeSpan ts = ToDate.Subtract(FromDate);
```

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly are you having difficulties with? Please post your current code.

Comment: @Mazen313 - what have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you just store the dates in normal datetimes, just treat them as any other date.

```
public TimeSpan GetDifference(this DateTime date1, DateTime date2) {
    if (date1 < date2) {
        return date2 - date1;
    }
    else if (date1 > date2) { 
        return date1 - date2;
    }
    return new TimeSpan(0);
}
```